# Rails Rspec - test records are in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

My app collects data from a website and parses some excel files on the local machine at startup.
How can I test this with Rspec?
I want to check that as soon as I start the app, some records are in the database.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like a suitable use of RSpec, or any testing framework. I would suggest simply raising an error if the expected data isn't present, so that the server doesn't start.